# Unable to run Zorba 3.0 with PHP 5.5.9 on Windows 7

Tags: php, windows, apache, zorba

I have downloaded and installed Zorba 3.0 on my PC/Windows 7.  I've already had Apache/2.4.7 and PHP/5.5.9 up and running.
I also have the following in my **php.ini** for Zorba:

**include_path = ".c:\php\includes"**
**extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext"**
**extension=zorba_api_php.dll**

The **zorba_api_php.dll** is from **C:\Program Files (x86)\Zorba XQuery Processor 3.0.0\share\php** and I copy it to **c:\PHP\ext** folder.

When I restarted my Apache server I got the following error in the log:

**PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\zorba_api_php.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0**

I had checked my Zorba installation by running zorba.exe from DOS prompt:

C:>zorba -q 2+1
</code -->
3

It is working fine.

Thanks,

Comment: Where is your zorba_api_php.dll located?

Comment: It's in C:\PHP\ext folder.  I found the problem with my setting.  I have another folder named PHP in my Apache: C:\Apache24\PHP.  When I rename it to PHPScript, the problem went away.  But now I got different error in the Apache Log:

Comment: Here is the error:<br>PHP Startup: zorba_api: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC10
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC9
These options need to match

Comment: Has anyone solved this? I have the same problem...